# Partial summation formula and integral

Tags: integration, analytic-number-theory

I have to prove that $\forall k \geq 1$
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \log^{k+1} x + O(\log^k x),
$$
where
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} f (n) = \frac{x}{k!} \log^k x + O(x\, \log^{k-1}x).
$$
I started using the partial summation formula (integral version) that says
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)g(n) = F(N)g(N) - \int_1^N F(x)g^\prime(x)dx,
$$
where $F(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} f(n)$.

I chose $g(x) = 1/x$ and $f(x) = f(x)$. So we have
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n\leq x} f(n) + \int_1^x \sum_{n\leq y} f(n) \frac{1}{y^2} dy.
$$
The first term is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{k!} \log^k x + O(\log^{k-1}x),
$$
while the integral is equal to
$$
\int_1^x \frac{1}{k!} \frac{1}{y} \log^k y + O\left(\frac{1}{y}\log^{k-1}y\right) dy.
$$
Now I don't know how to continue. I think the idea is correct. Someone can help me with this integral?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that it's true to first order in $\log^k(x)$. So just use l'Hopital's rule on $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log^{k+1}x}{\int_1^x(1/y)\log^k(y)dy}$, and you can also use this fact (after some extra additions) to deduce that the error is $O(\log^k(x))$.

Comment: Could you be more clear, please? Why do you compare the integral with $\log^{k+1}$? There is also che first term of the RHS that is have to sum to the integral...

Comment: If you want to show that $f(x)=g(x)+O(h(x))$, then the first step is to show that $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{h(x)}<C$ for some $C$. You've reduced things to showing your integral has order $\log^{k+1}(x)$, right?.

Comment: Thank you. So if I'm not wrong the limit is equal to $k+1$, hence the integral has order $\log^{k+1}$. The first term on the RHS is $O(\log^k x)$. The only thing missed now is $1/(k+1)!$.